# Границы сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, тип-сказуемого

Хочу узнать ваше мнение по поводу конструкций с глаголом "сделать". Как они рассматриваются с точки зрения синтаксиса? Для примера напишу две фразы:

> 1. Сегодня Костя сделал мне подарок. (имеется в виду любой сюрприз)
> 2. Сегодня Костя сделал мне предложение. (т. е. предложил руку и сердце)

Как бы вы обозначали сказуемое в данных фразах: "сделал подарок", "сделал предложение" или как-то по-другому?
Для меня тут лишь один вариант: простое глагольное сказуемое, которое в данных случаях представлено в виде нечленимого сочетания.

Comment: Почему бы не считать сказуемым только глагол?

Comment: Но глагол "сделал" сам по себе не несет никакой информации, если только не констатирует какой-то факт (сделал задание)

Comment: Ага, интересно, словарь Ушакова помог уловить это. Тогда просто "мне" пропускаем.